# Dollars and Cents (JAVA)

Tags: java

I need help with the calucluations for this java project i'm working on. The assignment asks me write a program that will spell out the number of dollars & cents based on a user numeric input. So, basically, the person enters a number like 815. and the program should output  "8 dollars and 15 cents").

This is the code I have so far.

**UPDATED** again

```
public class DollarCents
{

    public static void main(String args [])
    {
        // Declaration of variables.
       int dollars;
       int cents;
       String inputNumberString;
       int inputNumber;
       int calculatedAnswer;

       // Get interactive user input
       inputNumberString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Cents: ");

       // Convert String to int
       inputNumber = Integer.parseInt(inputNumberString);

       // Calculate the number
       dollars = inputNumber / 100;
       cents = inputNumber % 100;

       // Output the result
       System.out.println ("The Cents entered equal: $"+ dollars +"."+ cents);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks good.  What's the question?

Comment: What part of the assignment are you having difficulty with?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean "8.15 and the program should output '8 dollars and 15 cents'? Your original question states `815.`.

Comment: Well, I updated the code and Now I get an error message on the JOptionPane line. I don't know what the problem is and why it won't compile.

Comment: your probably missing your import (import javax.swing.JOptionPane;).

Answer (score 3):

Hint: use [String.split()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) and split on the decimal separator.

Everything that comes before it you can output as a dollar, and everything after it you can output as a cent. I'll leave the 0 dollar/cent situation as an exercise to the OP.

Note: I assumed the input will be `8.15` and the output should be as you stated. If you meant to input `815` and have the last two digits interpreted as cents, then you will need to use [String.length()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length%28%29) and [String.substring](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring).

Answer (score 1):

would something like this work for you?

```
// Calculate the number  
double amount = ((double)inputNumber) /100;

// Output the result
String output = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(amount);
```

Comment: Not in the finance industry. Never use floating-point for money.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your program will need to turn 101516 into "One hundred and one thousand, five hundred and sixteen dollars"?
You need to use the % modulus operator a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Build lookup tables of text, but be aware that you will have lots of special cases.

E.G.

```
String[] TensHundreds = {
  "No", "One", "Two", "Three", ...
  "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", ...
  /* Do we really have to list all next eighty??? */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual code included in the question is wrong! (version 9)

If you enter 5 (so 5 cents), the output will be:

> The Cents entered equal: $0.5

The user win or loose 45 cents in the process! The cents must be formatted:

```
System.out.println ("The Cents entered equal: $"+ dollars +"."+ String.format("%02d", cents));
```

Note: this post should be a comment but I am not allowed to do so